# What does active mean in the flag queue?

Tags: support, flagging

[image: enter link description here]

I notice that there's an block of bright pink with the words active next to my flag - what does it mean?

Answer (score 3):

When you see "Active" next to your flags in your flag history that means no action has yet been taken on it.

It will disappear when a moderator handles the flag or it is dismissed in the various other possible ways.